# Ubuntu 16.04 upgraded from 14.04 Dolibarr not available no icon

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, 16.04

I have just upgraded from 14.04 to 16.04. No dolibarr icon. Complete accounts lost and no backup made. I will also rather uninstall if possible. I have searched without success

Note: Dolibarr is an ERP/CPM software.

Comment: Since, you only upgraded, only clean installed 16.04, your data should be safe. Just install it again using the instruction https://wiki.dolibarr.org/index.php/Dolibarr_for_Ubuntu_or_Debian

Answer (score 0):

install phpmyadmin on 16.04
and dump dolibarr database (backup) (then save your .sql backup file and your current /usr/share/dolibarr folders and sub-folders (tar it) prior to save)
then roll back to 14.04
install phpmyadmin
install dolibarr create datbase with the exact same name of the backuped dolibarr database previously 
recover saved /usr/share/dolibarr folders and sub-folders
then restore you .sql database
that's it!!
should work !!!

Issue on 16.04 is not PHP if you use dolibarr >4.0.x.x but mysql server. Default 16.04 mysql server is mysql server version > 5.5 means not compialiant with dolibarr sql query

Comment: seems a rather odd problem.  what's the solution?  install from ppa?  or install which specific version of mysql?  surprised that SQL would change so drastically from version to version with MySQL.